# Span control with template lite

Tags: html

```
<table border="1" width="930">
        <tr>
            <th>Yorum Tarihi</th>
            <th>Yorum Yapılan Film</th>
            <th>Yorum</th>
            <th>Sil</th>
          </tr>

            {foreach value=users from=$comment}
            <tr>    
                <td>{$users.ADD_DATE}</td>
                <td>{$users.NAME}</td>
                {if $users.COMMENT|count_characters > 95}
                <td width="340px"><span id=comment12kisa_{$users.ID}>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:95:"..."}
                    </span><a href="" onclick="$('#comment12kisa_{$users.ID}').html($('#comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}').html());return false;">devamı</a></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID} ></center></td>

                    {else}
                    <td width="180px">{$users.COMMENT}</td>
                    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID}></center></td>
                    {/if}

                    <span id="comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}" style="display:none">{$users.COMMENT}</span>

        </tr>

     {/foreach}

    </table>
```

Above code prints this. When user click the link "devam", then screen becomes this.I mean it shows more related to comment. I use  tag for this. However, when it shows more of comment, "devam" link still there.How can i remove this? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is this "template lite" you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add in this to the onclick attribute:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jTruncate to show and hide "devam".
  $('#your devam contain block id or class').jTruncate({ 
            length: 200,
            moreText: "Show Devam",
            lessText: "Hide Devam"
        });
This is a jquery plugin. If u think something like this try this option.

Comment: Just add a css to hide that "Devam".  Display:none;